# Vaadin button alignment in HorizontalLayout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

When trying to set a button in HorizontalLayout, the button tends to be aligned with caption parts of other components in the layout rather than the component themselves. For example

```
HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
h1.addComponent(new TextField("Test");
h1.addComponent(new Button("Do Something");
```

will result into the button being aligned not in line with the text field but with its caption text.

How can one fix the alignment so that it is aligned with the Text Field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `HorizontalLayout` has the [setComponentAlignment](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.3/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#setComponentAlignment-com.vaadin.ui.Component-com.vaadin.ui.Alignment-)() method you can use for this.

```
HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
TextField tF= new TextField("Test");
h1.addComponent(tF);
Button btn= new Button("Do Something");
h1.addComponent(btn);
h1.setComponentAlignment(tF, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
h1.setComponentAlignment(btn, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
```

Perhaps you need another alignment mode, depending how you wish to align the components inside the HorizontalLayout

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else stumbles across this in 2021. `HorizontalLayout` now has the possibility to align all items with one method call (`setAlignItems`) as followed:

```java
HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
hl.addComponent(new TextField("Test"));
hl.addComponent(new Button("Button"));
hl.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
```

Comment: or maybe hl.setAlignItems(Alignment.BASELINE);

Answer (score 1):

In case it is as your example : one text field and button
you can do like this :

```
 HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
 h1.addComponent(new TextField("Test");
 Button btn = new Button("Do somethind");
 btn.getElement().getStyle().set("margin-top","32px");
 h1.addComponent(btn);
```

the 32px is 16px margin + 16px padding

in case it is something the accrues alot in your project
create a css class in your styles :

```
 .btn-with-margin {
   margin-top:32px !important;
 }
```

and add to the btn